# Why doesn't rm work as I expect here?

Tags: regex, bash, csh

I just want to do a simple thing. I got the following files in a directory:

```
AppInterface.h  baa  PEMsg.h  PluginInterface.h
```

Then I issue the command:

```
ls | grep -v ".h" | rm -rf
```

Much to my dismay, `baa` does not get deleted. But, this:

```
ls | grep -v ".h"
```

gives `baa` as I expect. So I guess the problem is with how `rm` takes input but I don't know why.  Tried this both in csh and bash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

rm doesn't take input from stdin so you can't pipe the list of files to it.

You need

```
 rm `ls | grep -v ".h"`
```

or

```
ls | grep -v ".h" | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: What does `rm` take input from then? And why the distinction?

Comment: Rm takes the list of files to delete from the command line only. The backticks `` version executes the ls and grep, and substitutes the output on the command line for rm. xargs does take its input from stdin, and calls the command (rm -rf in this case) with the input as command line arguments. xargs is better when there is lots of input to deal with, or complex processing is needed on the input before it is passed to the command.

Comment: You should be using `$( ... )` instead of backticks for readability if nothing else.

Comment: Using `$()` is standard POSIX and has been for some time. Backticks are faster to type, sometimes, but lead to a great deal of mess on lines requiring nested quotes. See [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) for documentation. It is certainly not unique to bash.

Comment: OK. I'm a bit behind with Posix it seems :) Does csh support this now?

Comment: @Paul: I don't know that csh supports it. Out of curiosity I just tested this with tcsh on FreeBSD 7 and it doesn't work, which is kind of surprising. So for maximum portability backticks may still be required, even though they're deprecated syntax. FreeBSD's `sh` does support this syntax, however.

Comment: Csh is in the OP's original tags for this question

Comment: Ah. At the time I saw it bash was also listed.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs):

```
ls | grep -v ".h" | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 2):

`rm` doesn't read a list of files from stdin, which is why it's not working. You cannot pipe a list of file names to `rm`.

The correct way to do this would be

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name '*.h' -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Using the versatile [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) utility. If you think this seems like a lot of work: that is the price of correctness. But, really, it isn't much worse once you're familiar with find.

Comment: find is def. the way to do this, especially cause you can check the output easily without running into trouble.

Comment: I'm not sure "the correct way" is completely accurate. It's simply one of several ways.

Comment: I am sure. All other options fail when filenames contain the space character. This method does not, so it must be "THE correct way". A big thanks for this lifesaver!

Comment: @Paul: Some will say `find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name '*.h' -delete` is more correct, which may be true.

Answer (score 1):

`rm` does not take its arguments from standard input. What you're probably looking for is command substitution (indicated by the backticks here), where the result of one command can be inserted into the arguments of another:

```
 rm -rf `ls | grep -v ".h"`
```