# Conditional remove in unix

Tags: unix

I need to remove all the files in the current directory except one file, say abc.txt. Is there any command to rm all the other files in the directory except abc.txt?

Comment: Check answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364907/why-doesnt-rm-doesnt-work-as-i-expect-here for solutions. It's not a one command, but usual unix style of doing different things with separate tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're after a succinct command, then with [extended globbing in bash](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing), you should be able to use:

```
rm !(abc.txt)
```

There are however several caveats to this approach.

1. This will run `rm` on all entries in the directory (apart from "abc.txt") and this includes subdirectories. You will therefore end up with the "cannot remove directory" error if subdirs exist. If this is the case, use `find` instead:

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \! -name "abc.txt" -exec rm {} \;
   # omit -maxdepth 1 if you also want to delete files within subdirectories.
   ```
2. If `!(abc.txt)` returns a very long list of files, you will potentially get the infamous ["argument list too long" error](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060). Again, `find` would be the solution to this issue.
3. `rm !(abc.txt)` will fail if the directory is empty or if abc.txt is the only file. Example:

   ```
   [me@home]$ ls
   abc.txt
   [me@home]$ rm !(abc.txt)
   rm: cannot remove `!(abc.txt)': No such file or directory
   ```

   You can [workaround this using nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob), but it can often be cleaner to simply use `find`. To illustrate, a possible workaround would be:

   ```
   shopt -s nullglob
   F=(!(abc.txt)); if [ ${#F[*]} -gt 0 ]; then rm !(abc.txt); fi  # not pretty
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your interest in providing a simple command. Is there any side effects using this? I see others are recommending shell scripts using if and a loop. Please suggest.

Comment: I believe a loop unnecessary for this case (and will choke on filenames with spaces if you're not careful). The `find` approach [proposed by deagh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456297/conditional-remove-in-unix/12456495#12456495) is a good alternative if you also want to delete all files within subdirectories as well.

Comment: There are some caveats to my solution. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: I sometime find putty throwing '!event not found' error. Can you please suggest.

Comment: What's was the command that caused that? Sounds like you've accidentally invoked the [history command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/understanding-the-exclamation-mark-in-bash). Make sure you use a parenthesis, i.e. `rm !(event)` instead of `rm !event`

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot reproduce that error so it's difficult to determine what's wrong. A quick fix will be to temporarily disable the history command by running `set +H`.

Comment: Oh, and I really wouldn't do `rm -rf ...` unless I'm really sure what files it will match. One false move and you may end up deleting more than you expect.

Answer (score 3):

1)

```
mv abc.txt ~/saveplace
rm *
mv ~/saveplace/abc.txt .
```

2)

```
find . ! -name abc.txt -exec rm {} "+"
```

Comment: If I had to do something like this - I'd go with 1)

Comment: @tsurko: Yes I also agree that 1) is better but i want to make my release notes simple with least number of steps.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
find /your/dir/here -type f ! -name abc.txt -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing you don't have file with space in the name, you can use a `for` to loop on the result of `ls`:

```
for FILE in `ls -1`
do
   if [[ "$FILE" != "abc.txt" ]]; then
      rm $FILE 
   fi 
done
```

You could write it as a script, or you can write it directly at bash prompt: write the first line and press `enter`, then you can write the other lines and bash will wait for you to write `done` before executing. Otherwise you can write is in a single line:

```
for FILE in `ls -1`; do if [[ "$FILE" != "abct.txt" ]]; then rm $FILE; fi; done
```

Comment: This will break if there are files with spaces in their name.

Comment: @ShawnChin, You're right. Specified it in the answer.